# Server isn't giving back a response using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with the $.ajax of jQuery. It's kinda weird because I use almost the same code on 7 other websites and there is works without any problem. Also on the webserver this code is saved, other $.ajax-requests work without any problem.

Beneath you can find my javascript-code:

```
<script>
    // Of course I link the jQuery file
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.jasperstuyven.be/include/js/test.php',
        success: function(responsServer){
            alert("SUCCESS - Answer of the server is |" + responsServer + "|");
        }
    });
</script>
```

The php-page is also pretty easy for this test:

```
<?php
   echo "TEST AJAX.PHP";
?>
```

The problem is that the server doesn't give back the text 'TEST AJAX.PHP' and I have no clue why.

Something other which is strange is when I use a url which doesn't exists, it still executes the 'success-action'. Weird, no?

Is there someone who can help me? I rewrote this code for 3 days and just can't find the mistake. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to see the content of the response using chrome's developer tools or firebug under firefox.

Comment: Are you testing on your local machine, or on the server itself? Could be a cross-domain issue. You cannot use plain ajax to access data from another domain, and if you're testing locally, your URL is pointing to another domain (not "localhost")

Comment: is that "<br" on line 5 intentional or a typo?

Answer (score 3):

Is the `<br` a typo??
Try

```
<script>
    // Of course I link the jQuery file
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.jasperstuyven.be/include/js/test.php',
        success: function(responsServer){
            alert("SUCCESS - Answer of the server is |" + responsServer + "|");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, The <br is left because I didn't delete the whole '<br>'. It's the first time I post a question here and I was messing around with adding code.

Yesterday I tried on some other computers and it turns out it works well on them. So I cleared my cache and tried again but it still didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @JS-Websites Well, if it works on other computers (same browser same everything?) then are you sure you cleared all cash/cookies everyting? Try with another browser.